# search and replace an element, using xslt 3, the replacement phrase is the same

Tags: xslt-3.0

while i have as input an xml file like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk102">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
          <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
          an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
          of the world.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk103">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
          <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
          society in England, the young survivors lay the 
          foundation for a new society.</description>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

and i try to find the best way to have the following info in a file, or in the xsl itself:

```
value to search for: 
An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.
add location:
on the self
value to search for:
A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.
add location:
on the self
```

so if i made a comma separated input file, it would look like:

```
"An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.","on the self"
"A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.","on the self"
```

i have tried with xslt 2, but i keep getting errors like a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable $search_phrase...

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>to be checked</description>
      <location>on the self</location>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>to be checked</description>
      <location>on the self</location>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Could someone give me an example with xslt-3.0 where probably i could replace the above phrases, and add the needed elements as well, wherever there is a match?

What i need to do:

in the full xml file, there are many records that can have the same description. I also need to make an exact match on the description: The phrase
"An in-depth look at creating applications with XML, authored by ..."
should not be matched. And in my case, i have also a description where the difference is only the case for instance, "an in-depth look at creating applications with XML." should not be also matched. Since in my code i use lowercase, this may also be the problem, but not sure... Whenever there is a match, the location specified along the search term, must be added into the location element, which currently does not exist in any record in the xml.

Comment: At least explain in more detail what you want to achieve: do you only want to match on the `description` elements or on all elements and/or attributes? Do you want to add the `location` element based on the text and replacement or is that a separate task? As for the match, does the element have to match the text completely or do you also want to match and replace partial matches in the data of an element?

Comment: And can there only be one match and replacement per element or can you have several ones (e.g. `<description>This is some text with two search terms.</description>` and `value to search for: text` and `value to search for: search`.

Comment: yes, i would like to match only on the description elements. The same description may be found in many records. but each record has only one description. I also need a way to specify the search term and the location that will be added in the code or in a separate file. Could it be a comma or tab separated file? Something like: "An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.","on the self" "A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.","on the self"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion on how to compare the `description` elements to a sequence of strings passed in as a parameter (but you could of well read it in from a file):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="new" as="xs:string" select='"on the self"'/>

  <xsl:param name="replace" as="xs:string" select="'to be checked'"/>

  <xsl:param name="search" as="xs:string*"
    select='"An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.",
"A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world."'/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="description[. = $search]">
      <xsl:copy>{$replace}</xsl:copy>
      <location>{$new}</location>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Works fine at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbk, but only after editing the sample to have all description data on one line.

If that is not the case then changing the template to

```
  <xsl:template match="description[normalize-space() = $search]">
      <xsl:copy>{$replace}</xsl:copy>
      <location>{$new}</location>
  </xsl:template>
```

should help: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbk/1

If you have several terms to relate to each other than some XML format seems be more appropriate to structure the data, so in

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="data-url" as="xs:string" select="'data.xml'"/>

  <!-- if you want to load from a file use xsl:param name="replacement-doc" select="doc($data-url)" -->
  <xsl:param name="replacement-doc">
    <root>
        <search>
            <term>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</term>
            <replacement>to be checked</replacement>
            <new>on the self</new>
        </search>
        <search>
            <term>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</term>
            <replacement>whatelse</replacement>
            <new>something</new>
        </search>
    </root>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="search" match="search" use="term"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="description[key('search', normalize-space(), $replacement-doc)]">
      <xsl:variable name="search" select="key('search', normalize-space(), $replacement-doc)"/>
      <xsl:copy>{$search/replacement}</xsl:copy>
      <location>{$search/new}</location>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have made some suggestion to do that and have adapted the template. Online sample is at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbk/2. As indicated there in a comment you can adapt that approach to load the data from a separate file instead of keeping it inline in the XSLT.

Comment: the above is just fine, "have all description data on one line." this is the case i have, but the problem is that i would like also all locations to be a pair with the corresponding search phrase. so the match is ok, but how the replace variable and the location variable could be read as a parameter? The replacement value corresponds to the search phrase, and the location also corresponds to each search value. My example should be more generic

Comment: Can you pass that data in as some XML format? Seems easier and more appropriate to use e.g. `<root><search><term>foo</term><replacement>bar</replacement></search><search><term>whatever</term><replacement>whatelse</replacement></search></root>` to store and pass in semi-structured data than to try to invent some text format to relate some terms.

Comment: i would be willing to make an xml with this data, along the locations that need to be added accordingly. Even a solution with xslt-2 would be great, if this could be easier to accomplish. How then the xslfiddle should become?

Comment: @yeri, see the edit for a suggestion on how to use XML to mark up the terms and process them with XSLT.

Comment: giving the input search and replace data as XML was the biggest help, i will keep this for now on, thank you very much